# Powershell insert XML here-string into xml document

Tags: powershell, xmldocument, xmlnode

I'm trying to insert an XML here-string into a XMLdocument. However, the saved XMLdoc, shows: "System.Xml.XmlDocument", not the content. How can I fix this?

```
[xml] $Doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument

$updateNode = [xml] "<Update>                       
                          <Request>Test</Request>
                     </Update>"

#Create XML declaration
$declaration = $Doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0","UTF-8",$null)

#Append XML declaration
$Doc.AppendChild($declaration)
    
#Create root element
$root = $Doc.CreateNode("element","BrowseDetailsRequest",$null)

#Create node based on Here-String
$node = $Doc.CreateElement("element",$updateNode,$null)

#Append node
$root.AppendChild($node)
    
#Append root element
$Doc.AppendChild($root)
```

Output at this moment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BrowseDetailsRequest>
  <System.Xml.XmlDocument />
</BrowseDetailsRequest>
```

Comment: The problem is "CreateElement()" does not accept XML data type (2nd parameter). The 2nd parameter is `string localName`, which is the local name of the new element. Look at the signature of CreateElement() `public virtual System.Xml.XmlElement CreateElement (string? prefix, string localName, string? namespaceURI);` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createelement?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_XmlDocument_CreateElement_System_String_System_String_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really manipulate the text in the xml.  Use the objects to manipulate the xml.  So you need to create an element for update and request and then assign the innertext value of request.

```
$Doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$declaration = $Doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0","UTF-8",$null)
$Doc.AppendChild($declaration)
$root = $Doc.CreateNode("element","BrowseDetailsRequest",$null)
$elUpdate = $doc.CreateElement("element","Update",$null)
$elRequest = $doc.CreateElement("element","Request",$null)
$elRequest.InnerText = "Test"
$elUpdate.AppendChild($elRequest)
$root.AppendChild($elUpdate)
$doc.AppendChild($root)
```

Comment: This is so horribly clumsy. Isn't there any other way?